# Joomla Menu Item Specific Module Not Working

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I made a module in Joomla and tried to assign it for one specific menu link.

[image: module assignment]

But it doesn't appear in the page i selected (or anywhere). Only shows when I select Module Assignment as "On all pages".

How can i show my module only for specific menu item ?

Comment: stupid question but have you set the module from "**unpublished**" to "**published**" ?

Comment: Yes Its published. Module can be seen if i mark it as "On all pages"

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly doing everything correctly, so it should work if you are in fact on the right menu item page.  I see you have a few menus so my guess is that when you are browsing the front-end you are hitting a page which is different than the one you selected here.

Check out Advanced Module Manager extension, which gives you a lot more flexibility on module assignments.